# Mercurial merge losing existing lines

Tags: merge, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'm trying to merge a branch into the trunk. Trunk has file with code added but when I merge the branch into it, the code disappears. In the branch, the file is present but code is not.

I'm using TortoiseHg for the merge. 'Discard all changes from the other revision' is unchecked and there are no merge issues in the log. Why would the code in trunk disappear during the merge?

Comment: Any fix for this?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Ended up doing a manual merge using kdiff.